# Integrate a codepen iframe script into tinymce 6 and above

Tags: iframe, tinymce, codepen, tinymce-6

is it possible to integrate a codepen iframe script into tinymce 6.X?
Every time I try to integrate it the code is cleaned even if iframes are allowed (test with youtube without problem)

Best Regards
Aurélien